# Creating a layout as the screen shot given

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a layout as shown in the screen shots. Is that a alert dialogue ?. I tried it by creating the alert dialogue, but the dialogue width is not occupying the whole scree width.

[image]

Comment: This all layout is made up by using `ActionBar`. Try this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Answer (score 0):

You should build a xml layout file with the GUI elements as you have shown above.

Later you should, inflate these elements in your java class.

ex:

```
public class Header extends RelativeLayout   {
//default relative layout constructors here and call init(defined below) in each constructor.

 init() {
   LayoutInflater.from(mContext.getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.yourxmlfile, this);
   btnLogo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogo);
   etSearch = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
   btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
   mHandler = new Handler(); // for handling focus
   setListeners();// set your listeners here 
  }
 }
```